# Finding adjoint operator on $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $T:\ell_2\to\ell_2$ be the operator defined as follows:

$Tx=y$, where $x=(x_n)_n$, $y=(y_n)_n=\left(\sum_m a_{nm} x_m\right)_n$. Find $T^*$, the adjoint of $T$.

So we need to find $T^*$ which satisfies $$g(Tx)=(T^* g)(x),$$

where $g$ is a bounded linear functional on $\ell_2$. We also know that $T$ is compact.

Here's how I was trying to approach this problem:

$$g(Tx)=g(y)=g\left(\left(\sum_m a_{mn} x_m\right)_n\right)
=g\left(\left(\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}\sum\limits_{m=1}^M a_{mn} x_m\right)_n\right)$$

$$=\lim\limits_{M\to\infty} g\left(\left(\sum\limits_{m=1}^M a_{mn} x_m\right)_n\right)=\lim\limits_{M\to\infty} \sum\limits_{m=1}^Mg\left(\left( a_{mn} x_m\right)_n\right)$$

$$\lim\limits_{M\to\infty} \sum\limits_{m=1}^M (a_{mn})_n g\left(  x_m\right)$$

Unfortunately, something is not right, since $g(x_m)$ is not $g(x)$, where $x\in\ell_2$ is a sequence.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: **Hint:** consider $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=a_{ij}=\langle e_i,T^*e_j\rangle=\overline{\langle T^*e_j,e_i\rangle}$, where $e_i$ are the vectors of the standard ONB.

Comment: If $Tx= \sum_m a_{n,m} x_m$ then $T^*$ has to be $T^* y= \sum_n \overline{a_{n,m}} y_n$ (when it converges in $\ell^2$, which is clearly the case, if **$T$ is bounded**, for $y$ in the dense subspace of finite sequences).

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Can you please explain how your inner product works? How do we know that $\ell_2$ is an inner product space? Moreover, you have $e_i$ as vectors, but $T$ takes sequences, not single vectors.

Comment: @sequence: you have not mentioned in your question what is $\ell^2$. Usually this is a Hilbert space of square summable sequences $(a_i)=\sum_i a_ie_i$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Yes, it is that.